# How should one wait for a condition to become true in Chapel?

Tags: chapel

Consider the following simplified situation -- task A increments a counter `i` (while possibly also doing some work), while task B needs to start its task when `i` reaches a particular value. Task A is oblivious to the existence of B, so I can't assume that A can signal to B when the condition is met. B can however read `i`, although `i` could well be remote to B.

What is the best way (or most idiomatic way) for B to check to see if `i` has reached/crossed a value?

I thought of a few different options (some of which don't work) :

1. A simple while loop, with no body -- Does this lock the task, or does Chapel sometimes yield from the while loop? Also, I assume the correct procedure would be to execute the while loop on the `i`'s locale.
2. Using atomics and the waitFor method -- unfortunately, this doesn't work, since it's possible that `i` has already crossed the value of interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a little ugly, but you can implement a slight variation of [waitFor()](https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/blob/cd343eef9d6497cb1aef4cfc0fc3d6105457768e/modules/internal/Atomics.chpl#L823-L831). Something like:

```
on i {
  while i.read() < valueOfInterest {
    chpl_task_yield();
  }
}
```

Note that you have to explicitly do a `chpl_task_yield()` yourself. Chapel will not automatically insert yields into a loop or anything.

You can also make a wrapper:

```
proc waitUntil(i, valueOfIterest) where isAtomic(i) {
  on i {
    while i.read() < valueOfIterest {
      chpl_task_yield();
    }
  }
}
waitUntil(i, valueOfInterest);
```

Ideally the signature would be more like `proc waitUntil(i: atomic(?t), valueOfInterest: t)`, but that's not supported today.

Comment: Thanks! Here's a somewhat related question -- does ``i`` need to be atomic, if the only process changing it is A?

Comment: If A is the only task writing to `i`, you _might_ be able to get away without using an atomic, but you'll need to have some sort of memory fence for other tasks that are reading. I wouldn't trust myself to write that code, so I would just stick with an atomic and change it later if it seems to be a performance bottleneck.